# How do I get invoice associated with a credit memo in Magento?

Tags: magento, invoice

I am assuming that every credit memo is associated with an invoice in magento. If I am right, given a credit memo object i.e $creditmemo, how do i get the invoice id related to that credit memo?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is incorrect.  A credit memo in Magento notes when a credit was issued related to a particular **order**, and not to a particular invoice.  Every credit memo object has an `order_id` data field.  This relates it back to a particular order.

The best you'll be able to do is load a collection of invoices using the order ID (every invoice also has an `order_id`), and then attempt to determine which invoice relates to a credit memo (if any).  Without knowing your background or what you've tried so far, it's a little hard to advise w/r/t to specific code.

Comment: I do believe that in Magento you are able to either credit memo against an order or an invoice.

Comment: $this->getCreditmemo()->getInvoice() , so somehow we have to get the invoice associated with creditmemo to process refund online